# How can I create a singleton (a class from an exernal jar) in Apache Tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat, jena

I have read the question[How can I create a singleton in Apache Tomcat startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792374/how-can-i-create-a-singleton-in-apache-tomcat-startup) carefully.But my problem is that the singleton is not an instance of a class I defined myself.It nedds to be an instance of an external jar.How should I create an singleton from a external jar? 
My case is that I want to use Jena to create an OWLModel,which need to be a singleton and will be used by all servlets.But the OWLModel class is from an external jar,not a class created by myself. 
I'm fresh to Tomcat,I hope to get help.Thank you!

Comment: use some kind of wrapper around the external class instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of a more direct JEE problem of sharing objects between servlets.

When I do this (including for Jena models), I tend to *not* take a pure JEE method for solving this. My approaches would tend to be:

- (**Recommended**) [Use an EE dependency injection framework like Spring to inject a bean into the servlet](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html). This can be done without spring using J2EE facilities as well ([link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html)).
- (**hack**) Use a central factory/registry that I've defined in the web app that allows servlets to retrieve that singleton.

The hack is quick and dirty and doesn't require you to learn an EE framework in order to keep moving.

Somewhere in your code, define a factory for returning that instance:

```
public class MyFactory {
    private static final Model THE_INSTANCE = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    static {
        // Use this static initializer for any other model setup stuff.
    }
    public static Model getModel() { return THE_INSTANCE; }
}
```

Then within your servlet, you would retrieve the instance simply by calling `MyFactory.getModel()`. You'll need to deal with [Jena concurrency](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/concurrency-howto.html) on your own, in either approach, mind you.

**EDIT**: an important assumption of this is that the external jar is available on your classpath. This is managed when packaging and deploying your WAR. If you do not have the jar on your classpath already, then there is other work that needs to be done.

Comment: Both this two ways are good.As I'am a beginner, I choose the "hack",but as you mentioned, I need to deal with Jena concurrency.I just simply write as 'synchronized {return THE_INSTANCE}'.And I used an JenaModel wrapper by protege API.

Comment: Note that this becomes a classic concurrency problem at this point. Just because you guard _retrieval_ of the instance through a `synchronized` method, does not mean that your later interaction with that object is synchronized. The reference on Jena concurrency that I mentioned previously is not optional. You'll need to use [Model](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html)'s `enterCriticalSection` and `leaveCriticalSection` methods.

Comment: I would like to use these methods,but the situation is that, I get the OntOWLModel like this way.`JenaOWLModel jenaOwlModel=ProtegeOWL.createJenaOWLModelFromReader(in);`this method is from protege OWL API.and then `OntModel ontmodel=jenaOwlModel.getOntModel();` This is an Jena MODEL.And I need to synchronized the jenaOwlModel not the ontmodel, because I don't carry out write operation to ontmodel(the jena model),just read it.And I generated different ontmodel for different servlets uisng the above method.Do you have a good idea to synchronized the JenaOwlModel?

Comment: It may be appropriate to move that to a new question that focuses on the specifics of your problem area. My suggestions would depend on the workflow (The frequency/location of read/writes occurrences) and whether there are hard dependencies on libraries (do you _need_ to create your model using <code>ProtegeOWL</code>, for example).

Comment: Yes, I should move this to a new question.I choose to use ProtegeOWL because it wrap the some API based on Jena, it's easy to use. But I can't find the proper API to get the OjectPorperty and DataTypePorpery seperately,instead the Jena's ontModel have this API,so I change the JenaOWLModel to ontModel. Maybe this isn't a good way.Anyway, your answer have help me solved the question I proposed.Thank you!